# Java 8 Method references

Tags: java

As part of arbitrary method references:

Why this is allowed?

```
Predicate<String> p1 = String::isEmpty;
```

And why this is not allowed?

```
BiConsumer<HashMap<String,Integer>, Integer> b1 = HashMap<String,Integer>::put;
```

Comment: Do you mean _now_ or _not_?

Comment: Understood, because in the above case the arguments for put cannot be inferred. This will work BiConsumer<HashSet<Integer>, Integer> b1 = HashSet<Integer>::add;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you're creating a `Predicate` which takes one `String` as an input. This matches `String.isEmpty()` which does not take any arguments. The predicate only operates on the string instance.

As for the second example, let's examine the `put` method:

```java
public V put(K key, V value)
```

Since you're using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, this would be

```
public Integer put(String key, Integer value)
```

As you can see, the method itself is expecting *two arguments*. Since you want to pass this as a method reference, it also needs the `HashMap<String, Integer>` in addition to the two arguments.

```
BiConsumer<HashMap<String, Integer>, Integer> b1 = HashMap<String, Integer>::put;
```

Over here, you've correctly marked the first generic type argument as `HashMap<String, Integer>`, but you're missing the `String` argument which the `put` method needs. Unfortunately, there is no `TriConsumer`, but you can easily define your own interface for it:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TriConsumer<T, U, V> {
    void accept(T t, U u, V v);
}
```

The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is not needed, but it communicates the intent to the reader that this interface can be used as an assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.

Now you can assign the reference to `put`:

```
TriConsumer<HashMap<String, Integer>, String, Integer> consumer = HashMap<String, Integer>::put;

HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
consumer.accept(map, "Key", 123);
System.out.println(map.get("Key")); // prints 123
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it so nicely!

Comment: @VijayNarayanan I'm glad I could help! Be sure to take a look at Bohemian's answer as well, his example shows how you can assign a reference to a method of a *particular* object.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that `put()` is not a *typed* method - one where the type has method scope and can be inferred, it's a generic instance method - one that takes its type from the type of the instance.

Also, you have a mismatch with the type of the method reference and its generic parameters. I have assumed you meant `BiFunction`, not `BiConsumer`.

Let's look at what *does* work:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> instance = new HashMap<>();
BiFunction<String, Integer, Integer> b1 = instance::put;
```

If you really meant `BiConsumer`, this works too:

```
BiConsumer<String, Integer> b1 = instance::put;
```

As I've said, because the method takes its types from the instance, so you need a typed instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!